# Howto check on arcgisserver if service (published map) is started?

Tags: scheduling, arcgis-server

I have an ArcGIS Server from Esri running and I need to check every hour if some published services (maps) are running. WMS and WFS.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriServer/IServerObjectAdmin_GetConfigurationStatus_Example.htm) (albeit in VB6) from the ESRI website that demonstrates how to get a reference to the [IServerObjectConfigurationStatus](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriServer/IServerObjectConfigurationStatus.htm) interface on a specific map service.

Once you have that reference, use the [Status](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriServer/IServerObjectConfigurationStatus_Status.htm) property on the [IServerObjectConfigurationStatus](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriServer/IServerObjectConfigurationStatus.htm) interface to check the status of the service. If the value is [esriConfigurationStatus.esriCSStarted](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriServer/esriConfigurationStatus.htm), then the service is started.

Then, it's just a matter of choosing the type of application you want to use to perform the check, whether a service or a scheduled application or a component of a larger application.